# Bat to open webpage, choose from dropdown menu and automatically input proxy login

Tags: windows, google-chrome, proxy, batch-file, dropdownlist

I'd like to run a bat that opens an specific webpage on Google Chrome, input proxy username and password right after launching the internet browser and pick an option from a dropdown menu.

For the dropdown menu, I know I have to look at the source code but I have no clue how to input such at a bat file.

This is what I've got so far in my .bat

```
@echo off
:Restart
start /w "google" /wait "C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://example.com
goto Restart
```

And here's the options I have from the source code

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <select id="ThrottleDropdown" class="form-control" data-bind="value: throttle, event: { change: applySettings }" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                            <option value="1"> Low </option>
                            <option value="2" selected="selected">Medium</option>
                            <option value="3">High</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into automation software, such as Selenium.  What you want to accomplish above is very simple using Selenium, but there is a bit of a learning curve unless you use the IDE version where you can "record" a script and play it back. Otherwise you would also need to know one of the programming languages that Selenium supports, like Java, Javascript, Python, etc.

Comment: Thank you!

It's been 5 days since I took your advice and now everything seems to be working. I'm just having issues with some Unknown Error from the Eclipse Console just when I start Headless Mode.